# how do i fix MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

i click on the button here is the code

```
//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:self.urlFile];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
_moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

and it plays but when i press the Done button, here is the method

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];


    [player stop];
    player.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];


}
```

it looks like this

sorry dont have enough to post image

it has the black lining on the bottom and the play button disappears as well, how do i load it back to the point it was when the cell was pressed and came to the detailViewController